# I can't render my video

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to render animation but I can't chose any video file.
I set the file format and container for a video and rendered from "render animation".
How can I render a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a path to the folder there you want to save the video file in the **output** field. Video will be saved here than you run **Render Animation** command

[image]